# environment variable not showing after set

Tags: macos, catalina, environment-variables

I am trying to set permanent environmental variable in my mac machine
I have tried following steps till now -

1. `vi ~/.bash_profile`
2. adding my variable

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
   export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
   export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
   ```
3. restarted the bash

   ```
   source ~/.bash_profile
   ```

For current terminal its loaded the variable, but if I open another terminal 
its not showing newly added variable if I check with `printenv`.

How can I make `bash` set the variables?

Comment: `source` doesn't restart, it just reads the file. Did you check whether you actually are using `bash` or whether you run `zsh` instead (which is the default for newly created accounts in Catalina)?

Comment: @nohillside  by defualt its zsh, and thanks u guided to the right direction , i need to add in .zshrc , now its working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For newly created accounts Catalina uses `zsh` instead of `bash`, so you need to add the lines to the appropriate file (probably `~/.zshenv` to make sure it's read in all cases).